# C++ QClipboard : trying to copy text from Qt application and to paste in Notepad++ raises 0xC0000374 A heap has been corrupted error

Tags: c++, qt, clipboard

I'm developping a C++ Qt desktop application for Windows.
I'm using the version 6.4 of Qt and I compile the code with MSVC 2019 (19.29.30146 for x64).

I would like to be able to copy a text from the Qt application and to paste it in another program (like Notepad++).
Unfortunately, as soon as I try to paste the content of the clipboard, I got the " 0xC0000374 A heap has been corrupted" error.

The code I use to make a very simple test is the following:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    ...
 
    QClipboard *clipboard = QGuiApplication::clipboard();
    clipboard->setText("random text");

    MainWindow main_window;
    main_window.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Does anyone encounter the same problem?
Any ideas to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AlexanderSobetskiy, no it's a static method: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qguiapplication.html#clipboard

Comment: Run it through your debugger, it should point you to where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that the "heap has been corrupted" error occurs only when the MSVC Sanitizer is actived (i.e. when the option -fsanitize=address is passed to the compiler).

As long as I compile with the "normal" Debug mode, everything works fine.